# Cursors instead of OFFSET and ORDER BY not_unique_column

Tags: sql, mysql, pagination

I use a javascript table (Datatables) that provides my server script with the classic OFFSET and LIMIT information to implement pagination.

I have modified this to supply the previous row and can thus implement a database cursor. This works perfectly when sorted by a unique id. But if you sort by a column that is not unique, then the current page may end up in the middle of identical entries and a WHERE not_unique_column > 'the previous value' LIMIT X no longer works to find the exact location.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: _"Is there a solution for this?"_ - Yes: always add a unique column as the final sorting criteria in the actual SQL that gets executed.

Comment: _"and can thus implement a database cursor."_ - No, you haven't implemented a 
 `CURSOR` because your approach is not stateful. (But that's a _good thing_: `CURSOR` objects are slow, heavy, lumbering beasts that have no reason for being in 2023). You might want to look at adding an "anchor" parameter to your pagination system so that newly inserted items (or removed items) won't mess-up users' pages in-between page-loads.

Comment: @Dai You mean ORDER by not_unique_column, id? And then WHERE not_unique_column >= 'previous value' AND id > 'previous id'? This is how I saw it in tutorials. But then all rows would be dropped out, which have a higher value at the sorted column, but a lower value at the id. How do you do this correctly?

Comment: Correct, `ORDER BY nonuniqueCol, id` will work (assuming `id` is a singular `IDENTITY` primary-key column). As for anchored paging, it's too complicated for me to explain in an SO comment-reply, but one possible approach is to only perform the search query _once_ and to save only the results' keys (in sorted-order) to a temporary table that expires after a few minutes - this means that looking-up subsequent pages doesn't require a full search.

Comment: @Dai I've been thinking about temporary tables and would have to test how quickly those can be built with a few million records. You would have to recreate them every time someone changes the sorting. It would ne nice if you could answer my  WHERE question, how that must look with the ORDER BY nonuniqueCol, id?

Comment: You don't need any `WHERE` clause (beyond what is used for filtering prior to pagination) - and you shouldn't need to process millions of rows for each search, assuming a page-size of 20 and caching of the first 10 pages of results, that's only 200 rows - you could even hold those 200 rows in-memory instead of in the DB (depending on if you're using a single-server or a web-farm).

Comment: @Dai But how do I load the next pages without something like WHERE nonuniqueCol > [previousValue] OR (nonuniqueCol = [previousValue] AND id > [previousID])?

Comment: @Dai Cursors can be very efficient if used the right way. Instead of loading 143k rows in memory and then process them all at once, the rows can be buffered and processed by the app in smaller chunks, thus reducing the app memory consumption. This seems to be a different use case, not the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`, as you were doing before.

Understand that as the client advances through pages, the queries get slower and slower, because MySQL generates a new result set each time, and has to examine a lot of rows to discard the rows equal to the `OFFSET`.

In other words, this query potentially has to examine 500010 rows to return 10 rows:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 10 OFFSET 500000;
```

It's understandable that the query that "offsets" by querying rows greater than the last unique value fetched by the previous query is attractive, because it avoids this.

But that method has two downsides: It works only if the client is advancing through pages one by one in an ascending order, and it does not work if your query result doesn't include a unique column.

An alternative I have seen used successfully is to use the traditional `LIMIT...OFFSET` query, but generate a sort of "mega-page" consisting of multiples of the desired page size. It's still a finite length, i.e. you won't return the whole table. But it's enough to return a larger batch to the client. Then implement paging as display logic in the client using CSS to show or hide pages. Paging then becomes very quick, for the first N pages, up to the size of the batch. If the client still needs to view more pages, then call to back-end to get the next full batch.

It doesn't make the SQL query any faster, but it reduces the need to run so many queries. And it might eliminate the need to run more than the first query for each client if a typical client gives up before they exhaust the first batch of pages. This is often the case, but it depends on the type of application and the type of client. You can verify how far clients typically page through results by logging the page requests for a few days and analyzing your logs later. Use this to guide how big of a batch you need to make in the first query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will use a mixture of several approaches. Cursors when scrolling page by page and OFFSET for larger jumps. Hoping people will use filters or search instead of jumping around in the huge table.